# What are the effect of radioactivity on grey wolves in Chernobyl?

Tags: genetics, zoology, proteins, molecular-genetics, radiation

I am doing some research about the effects that radioactivity has and is having on grey wolves in Chernobyl and more particularly on their genetics, but maybe also looking at the populations in the area as a whole.

I was wondering if anyone has any knowledge or resources they could share. It would be great!

Comment: Is there evidence that the radiation has any effect at all?  Other than keeping most humans out of the area, of course.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to point out that I am not only researching the effects that radiation has on wolves now, but also on wolves that were present in the area not long after the disaster. Surely the radiation should have caused genetic mutations in those wolves.